# Linux wireless subset of "iw reg set DE" and regulation-allowed wifi channels

Tags: wifi, lede

I am a home user, running a Linux-based WiFi-router in Germany (DLink 860L with LEDE-OpenWRT-Spinoff), trying to configure it to a proper set of allowed WiFi frequencies.

For "DE", the Linux wireless regulation database currently includes the WiFi channels 149-165 in the 5GHz band (frequency 5.725 - 5.875 GHz).
In Germany this range may only be used by organizations and it does require official frequency registration at the "BNetzA" (the german FCC).

Unfortunately the DLink 860L running LEDE is technically capable of using these frequencies and when configured as "DE", it seems to automatically adds them to the list of allowed channels it will use, when channel selection is set to "auto".

My current workaround to avoid trouble is, to use reg set "BE" (meant for Belgium), as this currently matches the correct set of channels for German non-commercial users.

I am missing kind of like a "DE-homeuser" regulation data subset that is like "DE", but without channels 149-165.
Is this a data flaw in the linux wifi reg-database or am I missing another config option in Linux wireless for configuring allowed WiFi channels?

```
"iw reg get":
country DE: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 14), (N/A)          <------ allowed for usage in Germany. But requires official BNetzA registration, to not get into trouble
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

country BE: DFS-ETSI       <--- although this is for Belgium, it's currently a more correct WiFi frequency option for German home users
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

Comment: On my system, the `5725 - 5875` line is missing. Debian, `crda` package version 3.13. Update your database?

Comment: thanks, the package name helped to do some research. Found this https://github.com/lede-project/source/blob/master/package/kernel/mac80211/files/regdb.txt.
So seems there are some more recent updates available for the regdb.

So obviously a LEDE/Openwrt package problem.
Yet LEDE does not seem to use the CRDA package to manage regdb.txt, its not on my system and not in the available packages.
But considering the question as solved, its now a package finding problem.

Comment: iwlist <iface> channel # can also be used to list what channels can be used.